# How long does a single level or battle in Marvel's Midnight Suns take?

Tags: midnight-suns

How long does a single "game" of *Marvel's Midnight Suns* take? I don't mean how long the campaign is, but rather how long a single "level" or "battle" or "encounter" takes.

I have a young child, so diving into a game that requires focus for long periods isn't ideal. Ideally, I'm trying to identify whether I can some meaningful unit of play into naptimes, playdates, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm requesting a quantity of time. That's specific and measurable, not subjective at all.

Comment: I see. I've retracted my comment.

Comment: This is highly subjective and varies. Different encounters are longer than others. Especially if you account for time in cutscenes etc. But an approximation would be anything between 15 to 60 minutes.